# Finding conditional PDF of $Z$ given $X=x$ where $Z=X+Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

Finding conditional PDF of $Z$ given $X=x$ where $Z=X+Y$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables.

Trivially $Z$ is normal. But $Z$ and $X$ are not independent.

When means and variances of $X$ and $Y$ are given, how could I get the conditional PDF of $Z$ given $X=x$?

I have tried to calculate using the definition of PDF of normal random variable. But it was so messy.

Any Hint for it???

Comment: $X$ and $Z = X+Y$ are _jointly normal_ random variables whose pdf can be found, for example, in [this recent question on stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/75010/6633).  There is a standard formula for the conditional pdf of $Z$ given $X$ when $X$ and $Z$ are jointly normal random variables.

Comment: @DilipSarwate What does it mean 'jointly normal'? Is it about a multivariate normal distribution of random vector?(Now I'm really confusing, since I not yet learned about 'random vector'. But I have to find this conditional PDF using 'random vector' :(... )

Comment: Yes, jointly normal means multivariate normal. The bivariate normal is often treated with multivariable algebra; with more variables, people use vectors and matrices in order to avoid long and complicated expressions.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Then I have to study it! Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For every independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with densities $f_X$ and $f_Y$, the conditional density $g_x$ of $Z=X+Y$ conditionally on $[X=x]$ is defined by 
$$g_x(z)=f_Y(z-x),
$$ 
for every $z$. 
Thus, $g_x$ does depend on $x$. Finally, if $Y$ is normal with parameters $(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$, then $g_x$ is the normal density with parameters $(x+\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$, irrespectively of the distribution of $X$.